# IntelliJ IDEA is only showing External Libraries in the project window

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition) and as you can see in the attached image, the project explorer only lists `External Libraries`[image].

I tried `Rebuilding the project`, `Invalidate Caches` and reimporting the `root pom.xml` from `maven` menu at right side panel, tried running `mvn idea:idea`, but still the projects files are not listed. How can I fix this?.

Note: I have quite a lot run configurations hence deleting the entire project and using a new clone is not an option unless there is a straight forward way to move all the run configurations to the new project (cloned to a different directory)

Comment: try configuring your project's sources folder?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project settings -> modules?

Answer (score 2):

Probably there was an issue with the project import. Try the following troubleshooting steps one by one to address it.

- Try to clear `File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart`
- Close the project window at `File | Close Project` and IntelliJ and try to reopen it.
- Open your project in OS file explorer and remove all `*.iml` files and the `.idea` folder from your project.
- Re-import the project into IntelliJ from Existing sources by selecting pom.xml - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to File> Project Structure> Modules(under Project Settings). There click "+ Add Content Root" and select your project directory. It will detect **src** folder which resides in your project.

I have solved mine using this method, hope it helps!